# Rows as columns classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, html-table

I have a table with below columns.

`app_role`, `app_desc` and `user_id`

We want to print the data in in below format - instead of data being printed in Rows, it has to be printed in columns. For each row in database, it should be printed in a column

```
app_role | app_role | app_role

app_desc | app_desc | app_desc

user_id  |  user_id | user_id
```

I need to achieve this in classic ASP

I will be using a record set to retrieve the data

kindly advise.

Comment: Have you had a go? What code have you written so far? What database? You'd just do the normal stuff and within the loop, you'd probably create a table repeating 3 rows and 3 columns for each row in the DB

Comment: If you're using SQL Server you could do a [`PIVOT`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2009/03/03/pivot-tables-in-sql-server-a-simple-sample.aspx).

Comment: @Lankymart is right - for an example, go to http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/37811

Comment: @JanuszJasinski You're on the right track but don't think that fits the OPs description, the source table should be `app_role`, `app_desc` and `user_id`.

Comment: Here you go http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1b1b7/1

Answer (score 1):

Presuming you have a recordset of RS, a very simple version would be

```
<% if not rs.eof then %>
  <table>
  <tr>
  <%while not rs.eof%>
      <td><%=app_role%>
      <br/><%=app_desc%>
      <br/><%=user_id%></td>
  <%rs.movenext
  wend %>
  </tr>
  </table>
<%end if%>
```

Or something like that but without more information, I can't be 100% sure. If you want one in a new cell then maybe this might work http://www.w3schools.com/ado/met_rs_getrows.asp

Basically put the recordset in an array and access each element itself.

As Lankymart suggested, doing it in SQL might be easier. An example can be found here  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1b1b7/1 presuming you have the correct version of SQL server

Comment: thank you so much for your suggestion, it is very simple to implement.

yes. i will be using record set with While loop to retrieve all the records. I would like to use a <tr> instead of <br> but i do not know i can adopt this. The reason by i need a separate TR is for each different field, i need to apply a different style.

Comment: You can wrap a <span></span> or <div></div> around each element with a different class if you want them styled differently